# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError，After Upgrade kotlin gradle plugin to 1.5.20

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I want upgrade kotlin gradle plugin from [`1.4.32`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1430.html) to [`1.5.20`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1520.html)，but some code occurred error in lower android version device，such as `Xiaomi 5.1.1` & `Oppo 6.0.1` & `Pixel2 6.0`, but it normal in Android 10 devices.

The error info:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Couldn't find com.example.kotlinupgradedemo.ProgressDialogKt.<clinit>[]
    at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.indexToMethod(AnnotationAccess.java:608)
    at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getEnclosingMethodOrConstructor(AnnotationAccess.java:405)
    at java.lang.Class.isLocalClass(Class.java:1334)
    at java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName(Class.java:378)
    at androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycling.resolveObserverCallbackType(Lifecycling.java:153)
    at androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycling.getObserverConstructorType(Lifecycling.java:146)
    at androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycling.lifecycleEventObserver(Lifecycling.java:83)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.<init>(LifecycleRegistry.java:347)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:174)
    at com.example.kotlinupgradedemo.ProgressDialogKt.showProgress(ProgressDialog.kt:36)
    at com.example.kotlinupgradedemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12)
```

My some code(`ProgressDialog.kt`):

```
private val ownerToProgressMap = mutableMapOf<LifecycleOwner, Dialog>()

private val progressCleaner = object : LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy(owner : LifecycleOwner) {
        ownerToProgressMap.remove(owner)?.dismiss()
        owner.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    }
}

fun LifecycleOwner.showProgress() {
    val context = when (this) {
        is Activity -> this
        is Fragment -> this.context
        else -> null
    } ?: return

    ownerToProgressMap[this]
        ?.apply { show() }
        ?: Dialog(context).also {
            it.setTitle("Tips")
            it.show()
        }.let {
            ownerToProgressMap[this] = it
            this.lifecycle.addObserver(progressCleaner)
        }
}

fun LifecycleOwner.dismissProgress() {
    ownerToProgressMap[this]?.dismiss()
}
```

I just call it in `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        showProgress()
    }
}
```

For the complete code, see [demo](https://github.com/xing634325131/KotlinUpgradeDemo)

Comment: After move progressCleaner with a Declared Classes, it no longer report errors...

Code like below:

`private val progressCleaner = DialogLifecycleObserver()

class DialogLifecycleObserver: LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        ownerToProgressMap.remove(owner)?.dismiss()
        owner.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
    }
}`

But i don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to [AnnotationAccess.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/kitkat-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/reflect/AnnotationAccess.java).

Especially lines

```
    try {
        return name.equals("<init>")
            ? declaringClass.getDeclaredConstructor(parametersArray)
            : declaringClass.getDeclaredMethod(name, parametersArray);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new IncompatibleClassChangeError("Couldn't find " + declaringClass.getName()
                                               + "." + name + Arrays.toString(parametersArray));
    }
```

Then look to [Class::getDeclaredMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) documentation.

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified declared method of the class or interface represented by this Class object. ... **If the name is "<init>"or "<clinit>" a NoSuchMethodException is raised.**

Kotlin global property and companion object property initialization compiles to Java static initialization block aka **<clinit>**.

Puzzle complete. Move `LifecycleObserver` declaration from static property somewhere else and problem will be solved.

Why Android 5 and 6 only? I think it's just `getDeclaredMethod` implementation differences. We see crashes on Android 5 and 6 only too.